# Which variable cannot be zero in underdetermined system?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-rank

Consider the underdetermined system $Ax=b$, where $A \in R^{m\times n}$  with $m<n$. If the Matrix $A$ has rank $m$, my question is which variable of $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n$ cannot be zero? I mean if we apply rref operations for the augmented matrix can we determine which variable cannot be zero? any constraints for variables corresponding to the linearly independent columns in $A$?

Comment: Generally any of them can be zero at some solution. The only way is if no vectors in the null space have a component in that direction and a particular solution does have a component in that direction. This scenario where no vector in the null space has a component in that direction happens when the reduced echelon form has a row with only a nonzero element in that column.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, could you please add reference about this point? I would like to read more about it.

Comment: I don't really know what I would point to you besides any linear algebra reference. It boils down to the form of the equation that the reduced echelon form gives for your problem, which is always of the form $x_k=\sum_{j \neq k} c_{j,k} x_j + b_k$; the only way for there to be no zeros of this at some solution is if all the $c_{j,k}$ are zero and $b_k \neq 0$. This is reflected in the rref of the augmented matrix having exactly two nonzero entries in a row, one of which is in the augmented part of the matrix.